# How to sort results based on join table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have Account model,

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games
  def score
    account_games.map(&:score).sum
  end
end
```

And AccountGame :

```
class AccountGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

What is the best way to get accounts with the highest score? as you can see, score is the summation of related account_games score field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Account.joins(:account_games).sum('account_games.score', group: :account_id, order: 'sum_account_games_score')
```

which will give you a hash where the keys are the account_ids and the values are the total score.

You can pass a limit option to accounts to get the top x accounts. something like

```
Account.limit(10).joins(:account_games).sum('account_games.score', group: :account_id, order: 'sum_account_games_score DESC')
```

Comment: I thought I was trying to do close thing, but I wasn't even close :) anyways this gave me something like => {125=>#<BigDecimal:7ffdf1a67ba0,'0.0',9(18)>, 115=>#<BigDecimal:7ffdf1a67a88,'0.0',9(18)>, 126=>#<BigDecimal:7ffdf1a67740,'0.0',9(18)>, 116=>#<BigDecimal:7ffdf1a67538,'0.0',9(18)>, 117=>#<BigDecimal:7ffdf1a67290,'0.0',9(18)>}

Comment: mm but isn't there any more readable way to do so, like if u want to make more queries based on created_at , weather at account , or account_games ?

Comment: and why do i receive BigDecimal instead of values ?

Comment: Let me try to be more specific, what if I have email filed in account , and wanna show the result as [email, score] how am i supposed to do so ?

Comment: change the group: to group: 'accounts.email'.  you can still pass conditions to sum or call where before you call sum

Comment: but i'm still not getting the value format (#<BigDecimal:7ffdf61779a0,'0.0',9(18)>) what does that mean ?

Comment: ah you need to call `.to_f` to it to convert it to float :)

Comment: mmmm I'm not sure if i'm doing this right, seems the results not right tho , check out this plz , https://gist.github.com/cubiic/9053bd78330a5708e05b

Comment: look at my comment on the gist :)

Comment: First thanks for your welling to help here, but the problem is not with that, the problem mainly with wrong results i'm getting, i'm getting the results with like lowest scores i guess since always zero while i want highest scores