# Top Ranked Item from Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I shall start by describing my associations. I have 6 resources. NationalOffice, Programme, Village, Discussion, Conversation, and Change. A *NationalOffice* has many *Programmes*. A *Programme* has many *Villages*. A *Village* has many *Discussions*. A *Discussion* has many *Conversations*. A *Conversation* has one (belongs_to) a *Change*.

In each *Conversation* a *Change* is talked about. The *Conversation* then gives the *Change* a rank. This is the table schema:

```
create_table "conversations", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "discussion_id"
  t.integer  "change_id"
  t.integer  "rank" # 1 for 1st, 2 for 2nd, 3 for 3rd, ect.
end
```

What I want to do is the following: From the *Discussion* class I want to be able to pick out the top change. I have crudely implemented that with a helper:

```
  def top_change discussion
    conversation = discussion.conversations.order(:rank).first
  # Incase there are no conversations for the discussion
    if conversation.respond_to?('change')
      conversation.change.name 
    else
      'N/A'
    end
  end
```

If I take that up a level to the *Village* class I have an issue. How would I go through all the *Discussions* in a *Village* and find the top scoring *Change*? I would also have the same problem when trying it on the *Programme* class. And then the *NationalOffice* class.

This may be achievable through SQL or activerecord - I'm not certain.

I hope I have made myself clear - I sometimes have issues with clarity.

---

### Edit:

It has been made apparent that I have not explained the Ranks correctly. I shall now attempt to explain how they work:

Each *Conversation* has a rank. Each *Conversation* is about a specific *Change*. So, if a *Conversation* about *Change* 1 is ranked 1st in that *Discussion* *Change* 1 will gain a 1st. In another *Discussion* a *Conversation* regarding *Change* 1 is ranked 2nd. So *Change* 1 now has a 1st and a 2nd (3 points?).

2 *Discussions* each have a *Conversation* that talks about *Change* 2. One Ranks it 1st the other 3rd. *Change* 2 has a 1st and a 3rd (4 points?)

Over all, *Change* 1 was the top change - it had less points (higher scoring) than *Change* 2.

Hopefully that is clear. [This](https://github.com/Jragon/OTIS) is the full application on github, just for context.

Comment: For being your first StackOverflow question, this is a really well formed question. Congrats.

Comment: Based on your update, you need something more advanced than just a sorting. You need a summation and then a sorting. The answer will roughly look something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997289/how-to-sort-results-based-on-join-table-in-rails

If I have more time later, I'll give a full solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use has_many :through to achieve this.

http://ryandeussing.com/blog/2013/06/12/nested-associations-and-has-many-through/

Has_many through will add extra conditionals to join between 3 or more tables. So you should be able to use this for all the classes "above" Conversation.

Basically you can chain has_many :through as many times as you need to find the top conversation for any of the associated models.

In your models:

```
class Discussion < AR::Base
  belongs_to :village
  has_many :conversations
end

class Conversation < AR::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
  has_one :change
end

class Village < AR::Base
  has_many :discussions
  has_many :conversations, through: :discussions
end

class Programme < AR::Base
  has_many :villages
  has_many :conversations, though: :villages
end
```

In your controller:

```
class VillageController < ApplicationController
  def top_change
    village = Village.find(params[:id])
    @change = village.conversations.order(:rank).first.change
  end
end

class ProgrammesController < ApplicationController
  def top_change
    programme = Programme.find(params[:id])
    @change   = programme.conversations.order(:rank).first.change
  end      
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what you've done. I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Also, changes don't have the rank column. Only the conversations do.

Comment: I didn't fully read the question before I answered. I'm editing it as I'm reading it more slowly.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at this I'm not 100% sure I understand how it will work. I may have failed to make myself clear: each village has more than one discussion. So if I were to do _programme.conversations.order(:rank)_ wouldn't it return a list of conversations with multiple 1sts and multiple 2nds?

Comment: Well, I suppose it would. This is probably an application-level problem, since I don't quite understand how your ranks are distributed across conversations.

Maybe add more to your question about that?

Comment: In the edits I have hopefully explained a bit more about changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working through the answer with James Strong in the #rubyonrails channel on freenode irc network. Here's what we got:

In the change model we added two actions:

```
def self.with_rank(load_conversation=true)
  q = select("changes.*, SUM(11 - conversations.rank) as score").group("changes.id")
  q = q.joins(:conversations) if load_conversation
  return q
end
```

This went through all the conversations associated with a change, it then SUMmed all the ranks (but we made it so that higher was better. I.E. if the rank was 1: 1 - 11 = 10) and put it into the table as *conversations_rank*. It then joins the changes table with the conversations table.

```
def self.top_ranked(load_conversation=true)
  with_rank(load_conversation).order("score desc").limit(1)
end
```

This next little snippet returns the top ranked change. It's pretty self explanatory.

In the Villages model we added a action that merged the top_rank query with the changes from that model (Villages.changes).

```
def top_change
  changes.merge Change.top_ranked(false)
end
```

It also had the following association:

```
has_many :conversations, through: :discussions
```

This allows me to then do the following to get the top change's name:

```
@village.top_change.name
```

The biggest thing I have taken away from this experience it to break down big queries like this into small manageable chunks. For this we said:

1. Get changes with ranks based on conversions (their scores combined)
2. Get the highest rank
3. Get the highest rank within a village

Thanks again to jstrong in the IRC and all those who helped.